# How do I reattach a deep-cloned element to a reference-tree?

Tags: c#, reference, deep-copy, cloning

Today I hit an issue while using a reference in C#. My use-case is the following: I have a global configuration-object in a winform-application. When opening the settings-screen, the settings-part of the object gets deep-cloned. At the time of clicking the save button, the element should get saved back to the original reference. This is not working as I first expected it to.

I have prepared a dotnet-fiddle for you to take a look at the problem. If someone is aware of a way to solve this problem, I am more than thankful for your input. I am thankful for pointing me to the correction too (I am sure someone has solved this issue in a much much cleaner way).

1) We have an globally avaiable static object structure

2) At a point in time, a part of this structure should be deattached from the object structure

3) The deattached part will be edited

4) At a later point in time, the part MAYBE should be reattached to the original reference in the object structure again

I am a frontend developer and its pretty hard to express my problem with words, so take a look at my code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qzJqC4

--- For readers from the far future where links are a thing of the past ---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace DemoCloneAndReattach
{
[Serializable]
public class DogFamily
{
public DogFamily()
{
    PrettyDogs = new List<PrettyDog>();
}

public List<PrettyDog> PrettyDogs { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PrettyDog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfEars { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Note: The WriteLines will help you to validate the correctness of the solution. Thanks a lot!

        // Setting up
        DogFamily dogFamily = new DogFamily();

        dogFamily.PrettyDogs.Add(new PrettyDog() { Name = "OriginalDog", NumberOfEars = 2 });

        // Getting the dog with the name "OriginalDog"
        PrettyDog originalDog = dogFamily.PrettyDogs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "OriginalDog");
        originalDog.NumberOfEars = 3;
        Console.WriteLine("originalDog has NumberOfEars (expected 3): " + originalDog.NumberOfEars);

        // Checking if the originalDog in the List has the value updated (from 2 to 3). It does.
        PrettyDog checkDogOne = dogFamily.PrettyDogs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "OriginalDog");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("checkDogOne has NumberOfEars (expected 3): " + checkDogOne.NumberOfEars);

        // Now creating a deep-clone of the originalDog (this will result in a brand new object, not related to the DogFamily in any way)
        PrettyDog clonedDog = DeepClone<PrettyDog>(originalDog);

        // Doing something that should not YET be written to the DogFamily-reference tree.
        clonedDog.NumberOfEars = 7;

        // Checking if the clonedDog has not the same reference as the originalDog. As expected, it hasn't.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("clonedDog has NumberOfEars (expected 7): " + clonedDog.NumberOfEars);
        Console.WriteLine("originalDog still has NumberOfEars (expected 3): " + originalDog.NumberOfEars);

        // I want the behavior below, but automated (some kind of reverse-matching or -reattaching-logic to the reference of originalDog):
        originalDog.Name = clonedDog.Name;
        originalDog.NumberOfEars = clonedDog.NumberOfEars;

        // Maybe the  call to the solution would look like this:
        // Reattach<PrettyDog>(originalDog, clonedDog);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("originalDog now has NumberOfEars (expected 7): " + originalDog.NumberOfEars);
        Console.WriteLine("clonedDog has still NumberOfEars (expected 7): " + clonedDog.NumberOfEars);

        // Checking if the reference is set correctly (not only the originalDog-reference but the whole reference-tree)
        PrettyDog checkDogTwo = dogFamily.PrettyDogs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "OriginalDog");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("checkDogTwo has NumberOfEars (expected 7 - this is the tricky one): " + checkDogTwo.NumberOfEars);
    }

    public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return default(T);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    public static void Reattach<T>(T original, T clone) 
    { 
        // Logic for replacing the original with the clone without damaging the reference-tree
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you're not making sense. "Detach" should simply mean "set reference to `null`" (i.e. cause the object to no longer be referenced by the data structure). "Reattach" should mean "set the reference back to the object in question). _Editing_ the object should not be relevant at all, given the problem description. The code example doesn't help; it does nothing other than to copy property values from one object back to another. Of course `checkDogOne.NumberOfEars` is going to return `7`: that's the exact same object reference as `originalDog`, the property of which  you explicitly set to `7`.

Comment: Please improve your question so that we can understand what you're trying to do. Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how exactly that's different from what you want it to do. And for heaven's sake, leave out the cutesy dog paradigm; it distracts from the actual problem. Use short, simple, meaningless type and property names, so we can focus on the _real_ problem.